# Laravel 4.2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException on delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i'm new with Laravel, so have a project, a simple CRUD, but the delete method is not working when i try to delete the data, and i don't really know why. This is the error:

**Error:**

```
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    if($project->user_id==Auth::id()) {
        $project->delete();
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        Session::flash('message', 'You can't delete this!');
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'project/destroy/'.$p->id, 'method' => 'DELETE'))}}
    {{Form::submit("Delete", array('class' => 't2tButton text-center'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('/project/destroy/{id}', "ProjectController@destroy");
```

Comment: Are you sure PHP engine doesn't throw error regarding syntax? This one: `'You can't delete this!'` - You gotta wrap this sting inside double quotes `""`!

Comment: Good point @bad_boy, or escape the `'` in `can't` like this `can\'t`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a route set for `POST` but not for `DELETE`.

Try adding this to your routes:

`Route::delete('/project/destroy/{id}', "ProjectController@destroy");`

Or you could change your method to `POST` and keep your route as is, but to keep it RESTful it's probably best to change to `DELETE`.

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem hahahaa i just posted it, thanks anyways =).

Comment: @bad_boy he's gotta wait at least 15 min...but please accept once that time passed if it helped...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer, the error was on this line in Routes:

```
Route::delete('/project/destroy/{id}', "ProjectController@destroy");
```

the Route method needs to be `DELETE`